# Segmentation fault in popen implementation

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, popen

I have written this C program for implementing popen(). I am getting segmentation fault on running the code. 
I have tried using execl() instead of execv(), but getting same error.
Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



#include <sys/syscall.h>
FILE *popen(const char *command,const char* mode)
{
        FILE *fp;
        int pipe_fd[2];
        pid_t pid;
                        /* Assume child is writing. */
        pipe(pipe_fd);

    if ((pid = vfork()) == 0) {     /* Child of vfork... */
            if (mode[0] == 'r') {
                    dup2(pipe_fd[1],1);
            }
            else if(mode[0] == 'w')
                    dup2(pipe_fd[0],0);
            close(pipe_fd[0]);
            close(pipe_fd[1]);



            execv(command,"");
            _exit(127);
    }
    if(mode[0] == 'r'){
            close(pipe_fd[1]);
            fp = fdopen(pipe_fd[0],mode);
    }
    else if(mode[0] == 'w'){
            close(pipe_fd[0]);
            fp = fdopen(pipe_fd[1],mode);
    }
    return fp;

}

int main(){
        File*fp;
        fp = popen("ls",'r');
}
```

Comment: `popen` is a predefined system call. [Open Standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html) that's the first thing. Secondly, what was the error? Did you step it through a debugger?

Comment: I figured it out...segmentation fault was due to the second argument for popen as I am passing a character and trying to access its value using a pointer(mode[0])

Answer (score 0):

compiler should warn you about this code `execv(command,"");`,
execv not accept pointer to char as the second argument, just read
`man execv`